try compiling project to one .so file
# main.py
from functions import some_function
def main():
    some_function()

.
# functions.py
def some_function():
    print("This is a function.")

.
#compile
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
setup(
    name='main',
    ext_modules=cythonize(Extension(name='main', sources=["main.py", "functions.py"])),
    zip_safe=False
)

.
#try
import main
main.main()  # This assumes main.py contains a main() function.

when I run try it does: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'functions'
if someone has any alternatives that are isn't elf file I will be happy to hear.

This really isn't recommended. There's a few hacks to do so in the duplicate question but it's not really straightforward or the way it's designed to work
